# Bootstrap and Jquery with node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know if when I run those 2 commands:

```
npm install jquery
npm install boostrap
```

Than I add the two dependecies in my package.json file.
Than in my app.js file I code

`var $ = require('jquery');
 var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');`

In my index.ejs file do I need to put a link to a jquery file or a css file or I can use those libraries directly ?

If not, can someone please give the configuration that I need to use bootstrap with npm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest you user [bower](http://bower.io/) for this kind of stuff as they are going to be served as static. [Bower](http://bower.io/) requires a flat dependency tree, so it's easy to manage dependency conflicts (i.e. multiple jquery file).

To install bower:

```
npm install -g bower
```

Install bootstrap using bower:

```
bower install bootstrap --save
```

Bootstrap has jquery as it's dependency so it will be installed, you won't need to install it separately.

To see path of installed packages:

```
bower list --path
```

Now add those path to your index.ejs file. Currently you will see bootstrap.less path. To add bootstrap.css path you will have to find it manually. I think it's in:

```
bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
```

To get a clear idea take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450408/using-bootstrap-with-bower).

Hope it helped you. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

There is also a prebuilt bootstrap bower package called `bootstrap-css`. I think it will be better to use to keep things minimal and not install unwanted `.less` files.

```
bower install bootstrap-css
```

Thanks....

Comment: can you give me the code that you use in app.js file after ?

Answer (score 0):

For Jquery , yes you can, see the Node part here , you'll find instructions: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery

Or you can just declare the script file.

But for bootstrap , i believe that you should include the css and js files downloaded from npm (you'll find them in the node_modules directory) directly into the webpage , because bootstrap isn't really a package , it's a css framework.